# What is an intuitive/geometric definition of line integrals? Do they work in 2-dimensions?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-fields

I understand that we are finding the area of a curve given by some function f(x) over the area of another curve C.  (I've also successfully plugged and chugged my way through my homework, without understanding what I was doing)

These are some of the questions that I am a little fuzzy about:
 1.  Could I use a line integral in only 2 dimensions? (for example: to find the area between the curves y=x^2 and y=2x from x is in [0,2]?  If so, how?)
 2.  Moving to more dimensions, the formula my book gives me is:

∫<sub>c</sub>F <sup>**.**</sup> Vds =∫<sub>a</sub><sup>b</sup>  F(a(t)) <sup>**.**</sup>
    a'(t)dt

Where C is a smooth oriented curve, whose orientation is given by V and F is a continuous vector field. (I understand individually what each of these terms mean, but am having trouble understanding what this formula is finding.

**What, geometrically, is this formula finding?**